# a line in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

what'are the line meaning and aim in the  .htaccess file

Comment: You could get the answer by Googling in less time than posting here!!!

Comment: This is well-defined in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument). It's also not directly [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means if page not found (error 404) then user will redirected to index.php

Comment: Not really, actually. The *user* is not redirected; the server does not inform the client of the location of the error document (via a `Redirect`), it just issues a `404` header and *outputs the result* of the error document. I.e., it's all on the server.

Answer (score 6):

Let me Google that for you... [.htaccess Error Documents for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/error-documents-for-beginners/)

Comment: +1 and let me create a let me google that for you URL, try this -> http://letmegooglethat4u.com/?q=.htaccess+Error+Documents+for+Beginners

Answer (score 1):

It means that all 404s (i.e., [Not Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)) are presented with the resource located at `/index.php` (redirects to a local URL-path to handle the problem/error).

Further information in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Answer (score 1):

This line redirects your visitors automatically /index.php in case of an `404 - Document not found`-error